# How to determine the importance of variables in PCA using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, pca

I have come across many similar questions on the web but could not find one that solves my problem that I can understand. I would appreciate some explanation here to aid in my understanding. Thanks in advance!

So,

```
[COEFF,SCORE,latent,tsquare] = princomp(X)
```

I understand that for `coeff`, the columns are in order of decreasing component variance. But do I know the importance of my variables (original datatset), not the importance of the principle component (PC), as what the answer of `coeff` might present. Is there any way to rank the importance of the variables I have?

I saw that many statistic software are able to do this, showing which original variables contribute most to the plot, and which are the ones that can be removed to prevent over-fitting issue. Is there a way to do this with MatLab?

My objective is to plot the data in a 2D plot, meaning I will be using PC1 and PC2, which hold the most significant component variance. So again, how do I know which variables should be retain and which should be discarded?

Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about a projection of your data into 2D plane for visualization, then by all means take the first two coordinates of each point from `SCORE` - these are the coordinates you referred to as `PC1` and `PC2` in your question.

However, if you wish to know which are the two components **in `X`** who contributed most to `PC1` and `PC2` you'll have to find the entries in the first two columns of `COEFF` with maximal absolute value. Since the the first two columns of `COEFF` represents the linear combination of elements in `X` that produces `PC1` and `PC2`.

Comment: But as for the second part you mentioned taking the maximal absolute value in the first two column of COEFF. But how would you know which variables do these values come from? Are they rank in the same order as how I define them? Because I know that the columns in COEFF are re-arrange in order of decreasing component variance but I am not sure about the rows. Are you saying that the rows are not re-ordered and are kept in the order of my inputs?

Comment: Yes, I have problem with the second part. Sorry had some issues with the posting earlier....

Comment: @maureen Are you familiar with linear transformations using matrices?

Comment: A little I suppose... What do you suggest I do?

Comment: If you pay attention then `SCORE = COEFF * X` is a simple linear transformation of the data `X`. This way you can determine how the data affects the transformed `SCORE`

Comment: PS: Sorry, for the delay in reply. Some technical issues earlier. It's all fixed now...

Someone suggested linear regression to me. But I am having some trouble with that too because my model is not in the form of y=mx+c. I do not have a data of outputs available. Instead I have 28 variables, which are my inputs and I hope to see their relationship through a 2D plot.

Then again, my concept of linear regression might be wrong that's why I could not get the results ...

Comment: Anyway, my objective is to determine the importance of the original variables and to remove variables that are less significant to prevent over-fitting issue on my 2D plot.

Comment: @maureen sounds like you need to explore **feature selection**. good luck!

Comment: Thanks Shai! But any suggestion on how I should get started with this? I have read through the documentation of Feature Selection a few days ago, but am still not sure about it. Does the method SCORE = COEFF * X helps to solve my problem? Because even with that I am still unable to rank my variables in terms of importance right?

Comment: @maureen feature selection is a HUGE topic. you'll have to find the niche that best suits your needs.